# Using Tkinter With Concurrent.Futures / ThreadPoolExecutor Class

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I've been trying to combine the two, but the ThreadPool will not connect to the GUI. Is it even possible to connect the two together?

I am just using this as an example to learn how to use ThreadPooling. I'd like each name to be printed on it's own thread. Eventually I'll be using a Treeview to collect data from their own separate threads, but not sure if it's possible to use with the ThreadPoolExecutor.

Here's what I've tried to no avail:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Listbox
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.lb1 = Listbox(self, width=26, cursor='hand2')
        self.lb1.pack(side='left', fill='y', padx=20, pady=20)
    
        self.b1 = Button(self, text='START', bg='green', fg='white', cursor='hand2', command=self.start)
        self.b1.pack(side='left')
    
        self.lb1.insert('end', 'Aaron')
        self.lb1.insert('end', 'Billy')
        self.lb1.insert('end', 'Chris')
        self.lb1.insert('end', 'David')
        self.lb1.insert('end', 'Edward')
        self.lb1.insert('end', 'Frank')
        self.lb1.insert('end', 'George')
        self.lb1.insert('end', 'Howard')
        self.lb1.insert('end', 'Ian')
        self.lb1.insert('end', 'Johnny')
    
    def worker1(self):
        for i in range(self.lb1.size()):
            print(self.lb1.get(i))
    
    def start(self):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
            executor.submit(self.worker1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainWindow()
    app.title('Main Window')
    app.configure(bg='#333333')
    #center the Main Window:
    w = 500  # Width
    h = 420  # Height
    screen_width = app.winfo_screenwidth()  # Width of the screen
    screen_height = app.winfo_screenheight()  # Height of the screen
    # Calculate Starting X and Y coordinates for Window
    x = (screen_width / 2) - (w / 2)
    y = (screen_height / 2) - (h / 2)
    app.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    #app.maxsize(1400, 620)
    app.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to make them work together?

Comment: your idea of a threadpool is somewhat wrong, a threadpool is simply a pool that will execute a few functions in the future, treating it as a worker with its own internal memory (while possible) is ultimately bad design, because they are all sharing the same memory anyway, so if you want a worker with its internal memory you should be looking directly into the threading module itself, not into pools, as pools make no guarantee about who will execute any part of the code.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I've tried multi-threading as well. Do you have an example of what I'm trying to accomplish using the threading module?

Comment: GUIs are inherently single-threaded in almost all cases (`tkinter` is definitely single-threaded). If you want to do parallel work, the main thread is responsible for any GUI-related interactions; have it extract the data, pass it to the pool, and have it write any results back into the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

a threadpool is a high level task distribution concept, it must manage task distribution and synchronization between workers and the main thread in a sort of "event-loop" fashion.

problem is that tkinter has its own eventloop running on your main thread, and blocking it to run your "threadpool" loop is wrong, as the GUI will become unresponsive.

tkinter itself is not safe to be accessed from threads, and might crash, so the way you run the above code is to run it directly into the main thread without using threads, but if you want to use threads you can use the `threading` module directly.

```py
def start(self):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.worker1, daemon=True)
    thread.start()
```

the above code is **not thread safe** and the tkinter interpreter may crash, the proper way to execute functions across threads is to make all queries about the GUI in the main thread before passing it to the child thread.

```py
def start(self):
    labels = [self.lb1.get(i) for i in range(self.lb1.size())]
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.print_func,args=(labels,), daemon=True)
    thread.start()
        
def print_func(self, labels):
    for item in labels:
        print(item)
```

the above code is threadsafe as all the GUI query is done in the main thread, the child thread is only doing operations on the data away from tkinter, and is the recommended way to use threading in tkinter.

in order to issue orders from threads back into the GUI main thread you should use custom signals, and [queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue) for communication.

```py
MainWindow.bind("<<my_custom_signal>>",some_callback_function)  # called in init
MainWindow.event_generate("<<my_custom_signal>>")  # called in child thread
```

while issuing commands into the GUI directly from the child threads is possible, it's not recommended as it will not be thread safe and the app might crash or act unexpectedly.

you can run a threadpool from a child thread instead of your main thread if you must run a threadpool, but again it shouldn't interact with your GUI directly, you will simply have your main thread managing tkinter eventloop and the child thread managing the threadpool loop, which manages more children threads.

```py
def start(self):
    labels = [self.lb1.get(i) for i in range(self.lb1.size())]
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.print_func, args=(labels,), daemon=True)
    thread.start()

def print_func(self, labels):  # called in child thread
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:  # create child of child
        tasks = []
        for label in labels:
            task = executor.submit(print, label)  # just print in the child threadpool
            tasks.append(task)
        for task in tasks:
            task.result()
```

Comment: I keep getting the following error message after testing your 'start' & 'print_func' functions. "self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: MainWindow.print_func() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: @AaronCatolico `print_func` wasn't intended to be a method of the class so it didn't have `self`, i added it so it is now a method.

Comment: Yeah, but you still cannot return the data to any widgets using this ThreadPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures class. The program will just freeze or lock up.

Comment: @AaronCatolico yes, you cannot and shouldn't return data directly, instead as pointed in the answer, you need to generate an event, that will cause a function to be called in the main thread, this function should read a queue or some place where the data is placed and update the GUI accordingly, basically the GUI shouldn't "wait" for the work to be done, it will go on and continue its work and be "notified" when the work is done by an event in order to update itself, this is basically how GUIs are made.